# How to use a multiple file library with requireJs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd

I building a project with requireJs my file structure is the following:

```
js/
   lib/
       noty/
           layouts/
               bottom.js
               top.js
               ...
           themes/
               default.js
           noty.jquery.js
       jquery.js
       jquery-ui.js
   user/
      user.js
   app.js
```

And my configuration :

```js
    requirejs.config({
        baseUrl: 'js/lib',
        urlArgs: 'bust=' + (new Date()).getTime(),  //only for dev  : no-cache
        paths: {
            user: '../user'
        },
        shim: {
            'jquery-ui': ['jquery'],
            'jquery-tmpl': ['jquery'],
            'gridy': ['jquery']
        }
    });
    requirejs(['jquery', 'jquery-ui'],  function($){
    ....
    });
```

My concern is about to integrate noty which is a notification plugin that I may use in any modules. This plugin requires to load :

```
js/lib/noty/noty.jquery.js
js/lib/noty/layout/top.js
js/lib/noty/themes/bottom.js
```

I'm not sure what is the way to do that?

- Concatenate the files ?
- Load each file as a dependency? :

  requirejs(['jquery', 'jquery-ui', 'noty/noty.jquery.js', 'noty/layout/top.js', etc. ]
- Creates some kind of plugin/module for requireJs?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I managed to implement the 3rd solution: I've created a web module that wrap the library in a file named notiy.js :

```
define(['jquery',
    'noty/layouts/topCenter', 
    'noty/layouts/bottomRight',
    'noty/themes/default'], 
function($){

$.noty.defaults.timeout = 20000;

return  function(type, msg){
    var topLayout = 'topCenter',
        bottomLayout = 'bottomRight',
        layout = {
            'alert'     : topLayout,
            'info'      : bottomLayout,
            'confirm'   : topLayout,
            'success'   : bottomLayout,
            'error'     : topLayout,
            'warning'   : topLayout
        };

    if(msg && type){
        return noty({
            text : msg, 
            layout: layout[type] || topLayout, 
            type : type
        });
    }
}
});
```

I've declared the dependencies in the shim config (to fix the dependency order) in my app.js :

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl: 'js/lib',
urlArgs: 'bust=' + (new Date()).getTime(),  //only for dev  : no-cache
paths: {
    user: '../user'
},
shim: {
    'jquery-ui'         : ['jquery'],
    'jquery-tmpl'       : ['jquery'],
    'gridy'             : ['jquery'],
    'noty/jquery.noty'  : ['jquery'],
    'notify'            : ['noty/jquery.noty']
}
});
requirejs(['jquery', 'jquery-ui', 'jquery-tmpl', 'notify'],  function($, ui, tmpl, notify){
//...
});
```

Ans it works like a charm!

Comment: doesn't work. Both layout and theme js-files have dependencies to jquery and noty and those deps are not defined here.

Comment: jquery and noty are under the 'js/lib' so there is no need to define them

Answer (score 5):

or like this:

```
paths: {
    'jquery': 'jquery/1.10.2/jquery',
    'noty': 'noty/2.0/jquery.noty',
    'noty.themes.default': 'noty/2.0/themes/default',
    'noty.layouts.topCenter': 'noty/2.0/layouts/topCenter',

    app: '../app',
    util: '../util'
},
shim: {
    'noty': ['jquery'],
    'noty.themes.default': {
        deps: ['jquery', 'noty'],
        exports: 'jquery'
    },
    'noty.layouts.topCenter': {
        deps: ['jquery', 'noty'],
        exports: 'jquery'
    }
}
```